# $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] returns nginx reverse proxy port/name

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, wordpress

I am running WordPress under the following configuration:

Varnish (Port 80) -> nginx (Port 8080)

This is all working great except when some plugin or other tries to get my server name using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`. When that happens, it is getting back `_:8080` as my server name and port. This is what the nginx config has:

```
server {
listen 8080;
server_name _;
```

What I need it to return is *domain.com* but if I change the nginx config, obviously, it stops listening on the port it needs to be (8080) (but changing the server_name works fine).

How can I have nginx listen on 8080 but have `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` return the correct port (or rather, not append the wrong port)?

Answer (score 1):

`_:8080` **is** the correct value for `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` in this configuration. It's explicitly defined to return the value of `server_name`. From the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> The name of the server host under which the current script is executing. If the script is running on a virtual host, this will be the value defined for that virtual host.

It sounds like you are looking for `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. Note that you also need to have not configured Varnish to alter the `Host:` request header.

Comment: I agree... but I can't control what plugin developers are using to get my server name. Which is why I am looking for a work-around to set it to what they are looking for. I'll check into what we are or are not doing with Host in varnish. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can't control them directly, but if they're trying to look at SERVER_NAME then that's a pretty serious bug. Plugins should call `get_site_url()` to find the site URL, and parse it if necessary. You can always report bugs. You can't guarantee a developer will fix bugs, though...

Comment: And that's exactly what they did! I am updating the site now to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default value of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` by adding a `fastcgi_param` directive **after** the `include fastcgi_params;` statement.

For example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME  $http_host;
    ...
}
```

The value defined in the include file will be silently overwritten with the value of `$http_host`.

Comment: Excellent! I'll try this for the other plugin that does this (see below, one of the devs already updated their code)!

Comment: Keep in mind that this might not fix a broken plugin that is inappropriately depending on SERVER_NAME. For instance, this value will never have anything useful on a WP multisite subdomain install. The developer will still need to fix the bug in that case.